# Python как взять связанные поля по ключу?

Tags: python, sqlite3

У меня есть база данных с допустим машинами, их моделью и годом. Как при выборе марки авто, выводились связанные с ней модели?

Как пример:

| Марка | Модель |
| --- | --- |
| Haval | H9 |
| BMW | X5 |
| BMW | X6 |
| BMW | X3 |
| toyota | Karina |
| Haval | M12 |

Как при вызове марки, вызывать связанные с ней модели? Я Думал просто к каждой марке привязать ID и через них вызывать массив моделей, но что если я захочу в DB добавить еще модель, это надо будет лезть в код, и все переписывать.

Comment: Классно, таблица превратилась в кашу.

Comment: покажите какие уже модели у вас есть

Comment: Базу нужно нормализовать. Таблица с марками: id, название марки. Таблица с моделями: id, id марки, название модели.

Comment: Если добавлять id, то не получится ли так, что модели не привяжутся к марке, из за того, что я удалю дубликаты во время выполнения кода. Мне нужно как то привязать модели именно к названию марки.

Comment: А все, теперь таблица в порядке.